# I'm trying to align font awesome Icons next to a button icon and have them spaced out as shown in the example

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to align Social Icons front font awesome like the example below. I've attempted to target the Icons but I'm unable to modify the padding or margin. What am I missing?

https://dribbble.com/shots/10539405-Fast-Food-Restaurant-Landing-page - EXAMPLE

```html
<!--BOOTSTRAP-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- FONT AWESOME -->
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/919f10952e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- NAVBAR -->
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="margin-left:0px; padding-top: 0px;">Davidos</a>
    <ul class="nav justify-content-center" style="padding-top:5px;">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">HOME</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">ABOUT</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">MENU</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">GALLERY</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">BLOG</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">CONTACT</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- SOCIAL LINKS -->
    <ul class="nav justify-content-end" id="socials">
      <li class="nav-item"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">MAKE A ORDER</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Davidos Pizza and Wing's</h1>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.fab{
margin-right:25px;
}
```

```html
<!--BOOTSTRAP-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- FONT AWESOME -->
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/919f10952e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- NAVBAR -->
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="margin-left:0px; padding-top: 0px;">Davidos</a>
    <ul class="nav justify-content-center" style="padding-top:5px;">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">HOME</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">ABOUT</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">MENU</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">GALLERY</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">BLOG</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">CONTACT</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- SOCIAL LINKS -->
    <ul class="nav justify-content-end" id="socials">
      <li class="nav-item"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">MAKE A ORDER</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Davidos Pizza and Wing's</h1>

</div>
```